# Listview visibility

Tags: android, android-listview, visibility, onclicklistener

I am trying to make a listview visible when the user clicks on a layout. I have added setOnClickListener to the layout. But when I click the layout, the listview is not visible. Could you please help me out in this. Below is my code:

```
transparentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tarnsparent_list_view);


LinearLayout lt = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

lt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("On click listener");
                transparentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for (int j=0;j<sectionListItems.size();j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("section " + sectionListItems.get(j).toString());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> myarrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sectionListItems);
                for(int k = 0;k<myarrayAdapter.getCount();k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Adapter " + myarrayAdapter.getItem(k));
                }
                transparentListView.setAdapter(myarrayAdapter);
            }
        });
```

Below is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:focusable="true">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sep"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="seperator 0"
    android:textColor="#104E8B"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    android:visibility="visible"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.dlist.Stacklist
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.dlist.Stacklist>


</TableLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tarnsparent_list_view"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

    android:visibility="gone">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your Layoout xml also

Comment: Can you print sectionListItems size in Log ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see that in log

Comment: @Hardik These are the sectionListItem elements:
section abe
section abe1
section abe2
section abe3
section abe4
section abe5
section abe6
section abe7
The size is 8

Comment: @user370305 Hi, I have put View.OnClickListener but still no luck.

Comment: Ok. First check by filling static values in arraylist like 1 to 10. And check all values display or not.

Comment: @Hardik: Nope, still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u gave table layout height as match_parent. so u wont be able to see this as it ll occupy whole screen. so make it wrap_content or give it some value.

Answer (score 1):

Change you Table layout style like this

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent" >
```